# Using Two Controllers in a Single AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Full source code can be found http://plnkr.co/edit/rQSg5eMhm9uc9dSWnWEU?p=preview

In the index.html file if I use only one controller at a time it works.  That is if I use

```
<body>
    <div id="inputExample" ng-app="AngularJSTestBedWebApp" ng-controller="AngularJSInputExampleController">
        input example: <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" /><br/>
        This is the updated value: {{inputValue}}        
    </div>   
</body>
```

or if I use

```
<body>
    <div id="scopeExample" ng-app="AngularJSTestBedWebApp" ng-controller="AngularJSScopeExampleController">
        {{understandingScope}}
    </div> 
</body>
```

It will also work.  However if I use both controllers at the same time such as

```
<body>
    <div id="scopeExample" ng-app="AngularJSTestBedWebApp" ng-controller="AngularJSScopeExampleController">
        {{understandingScope}}
    </div>

    <div id="inputExample" ng-app="AngularJSTestBedWebApp" ng-controller="AngularJSInputExampleController">
        input example: <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" /><br/>
        This is the updated value: {{inputValue}}        
    </div>   
</body>
```

The second controller never gets used.  {{inputValue}} never gets assigned a default value and also never updates when you type in the text box.  It literally just says "{{inputValue}}" the entire time.

I'm sure this is probably something easy but I'm very new to AngularJS.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think you need to declare your `ng-app` only once for single applciation, so try to move `ng-app="AngularJSTestBedWebApp"` to `<body>` or `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) attribute should be placed at the root of the application.  In your example that would be `<body/>` or `<html/>`

```
<body ng-app="AngularJSTestBedWebApp">
    <div id="scopeExample"  ng-controller="AngularJSScopeExampleController">
        {{understandingScope}}
    </div>

    <div id="inputExample" ng-controller="AngularJSInputExampleController">
        input example: <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" /><br/>
        This is the updated value: {{inputValue}}        
    </div>   
</body>
```

[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eiLfbiK584sHTlqJzWD8?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much.  New it was something minor.  I can't accept for another 11 mins.  But I'll accept as soon as time is up.  Thanks for the help!!! 45 mins searching the web and 2 mins on here!

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete example of two applications in one html page and two conrollers in one application :

```
<div ng-app = "myapp">
  <div  ng-controller = "C1" id="D1">
     <h2>controller 1 in app 1 <span id="titre">{{s1.title}}</span> !</h2>
  </div>

  <div  ng-controller = "C2" id="D2">
     <h2>controller 2 in app 1 <span id="titre">{{s2.valeur}}</span> !</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    var A1 = angular.module("myapp", [])

    A1.controller("C1", function($scope) {
        $scope.s1 = {};
        $scope.s1.title = "Titre 1";
     });

    A1.controller("C2", function($scope) {
        $scope.s2 = {};
        $scope.s2.valeur = "Valeur 2";
     });
</script>
```